# SSL Returning Blank Page, No Catalina Errors

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, jira

This is my second, maybe third, time configuring SSL with Tomcat. Earlier I had created a self signed, which worked, and now using my signed is proving fruitless.

I am using Tomcat, operating from the Amazon Linux API. When using the signed cert/keystore, my server is starting normally without errors. However, when trying to navigate to the domain it is giving me an "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" error.

My server.xml file looks as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" 
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="/home/ec2-user/.keystore/starchild.jks" 
keystorePass="d6b5385812252f180b961aa3630df504" />
```

It couldn't hurt to also mention that I'm using a wildcard certificate.

Please let me know if anything looks amiss!

EDIT:

After looking more into this, I've determined there may be nothing is wrong with the Server.xml, or the listening ports. This is becoming more of an actual certificate error, as the curl request is giving me this error:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to jira.mywebsite.com:-9824
```

Though, I can't seem to figure out what the "-9824" is.

When comparing this curl to another similar setup (using the same Wildcard Certificate) it's turning up the full handshake, which is to be expected. I believe this is now between the protocol/cypher set default on JIRA servers.

Comment: What is the complete `curl` command that gave you that error? What does `openssl s_client -host jira.mywebsite.com -port 8443` display?